# spring boot vuejs aplication can't show unicode charecters correctly in the tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, unicode

Hi I am developing a full stack application using spring boot and vuejs the app works normally when I run it in the ide. but when I deploy it on the tomcat server the unicode charecters are not shown correctly.
my pom.xml for building app is:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                <workingDirectory>src/frontend</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Copy Vue frontend into Spring Boot target static folder</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/frontend/dist</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried to solve the problem by adding

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

to the tomcat server config.
please help me to figure this out.
this is the webpage in running on the tomcat:
[image: webpage on the tomcat]

and this is same webpage running in the ide:
[image: on the ide]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Share some examples for "_…are not shown correctly_"

Comment: Have you configured your own server or are you using Spring Boot’s embedded Tomcat server?